# filter jTable content for multiple textboxes and print output to a file

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am making a Java Swing app where a user can input some data into a JTable. The data is displayed in the table. I have added the functionality to import data from csv, export to a txt or search table for data.
But I am having problem with the searching part.

I have 3 textfields from which I want to take input and then search for the fields in the jtable and update it (according to hwo many fields have text in them), making only the result fields visible and then export ONLY THOSE result fields to the text file. The search input in the text fields can be present in one, two or all three of the JTextFields. I have added action listener to search button because it can be puzzling for the program if I added it to textfields (during new record addition to jtable, it will start searching instead).

I don't want to be searching according to all three textfields necessarily , meaning, I want to search jtable if one JTextField has user input to search, with 2 if two have inputs and with 3 three if all three are set.

Here is the reprex of what I have tried:

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableRowSorter;


public class main {

public static class RefSystemGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


Object[] cols = {"Publication Name",
        "Journal Name","Journal Volume","Conference Location"};
private DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();
private JTable table = new JTable(model);
private JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(table); 


private JTextField nameOfPub = new JTextField(20);
private JTextField nameOfJour = new JTextField(20);
private JTextField volumeOfJour = new JTextField(20);
private JTextField locConf = new JTextField(20);



private JLabel labnameOfPub = new JLabel("Name Of Publication: ");
private JLabel labnameOfJour = new JLabel("Journal Name: ");
private JLabel labvolumeOfJour = new JLabel("Journal Volume: ");
private JLabel lablocConf = new JLabel("Conference Location: ");


private JButton AddButton= new JButton("Add");  
private JButton SearchButton= new JButton("Search");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    RefSystemGUI applic = new RefSystemGUI();
    
}

public RefSystemGUI() {
    super("Bibliography");
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(4,4,3,3);
    
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    gbc.gridx++;
    add(labnameOfPub,gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;
    add(nameOfPub,gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;
    
    
    
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    add(labnameOfJour,gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;
    add(nameOfJour,gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;
    add(labvolumeOfJour,gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;
    add(volumeOfJour,gbc);
    
    
    
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    add(lablocConf,gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;
    add(locConf,gbc);

    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    add(AddButton,gbc);
    gbc.gridx++;
    add(SearchButton,gbc);

    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy++;
    
    gbc.weightx=1;
    gbc.weighty=1;
    gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    gbc.gridwidth = 8;
    gbc.gridheight = 4;
    model.setColumnIdentifiers(cols);
    gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    add(sp,gbc);
    
    AddButton.addActionListener(this);
    SearchButton.addActionListener(this);
    
    setSize(1080, 1080);
    setLocationByPlatform(true);
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
    BlankDisplay();
} //setLayout



    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {

         if(event.getSource()==AddButton) {
            if ( nameOfPub.getText().isEmpty()) {
            }else {
            
                 String PubName= nameOfPub.getText();
                 String JourName = nameOfJour.getText();
                 String JourVol = volumeOfJour.getText();
              
                 String ConfLoc = locConf.getText();
                 
                 if(PubName.isEmpty()) {
                    PubName = " ";
                 
                 }else if(JourName.isEmpty()) {
                    JourName = " ";
                 }else if(JourVol.isEmpty()) {
                    JourVol = " ";
                 }else if(ConfLoc.isEmpty()) {
                    ConfLoc = " ";
                 }
                
                 model.addRow(new Object[] {PubName,JourName,JourVol,ConfLoc});
                System.out.println("Data Entry Successful");
                BlankDisplay();
            }
        }else if(event.getSource()==SearchButton) {
            
            TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> tr = new TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel>(model);
            //table.setRowSorter(tr);
            
            table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
            
            
            ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>> filters = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>();
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(nameOfJour.getText(), 0));
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(locConf.getText(), 1));
            filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(nameOfPub.getText(), 2));
            //RowFilter<Object,Object> rf = RowFilter.andFilter(filters);
            tr.setRowFilter(RowFilter.orFilter(filters));
            table.setRowSorter(tr);
            
            List<RowSorter.SortKey> sortKeys = new ArrayList<>();
            int columnIndexToSort = 2;
            sortKeys.add(new RowSorter.SortKey(columnIndexToSort, SortOrder.ASCENDING));
            tr.setSortKeys(sortKeys);
            
        }
        BlankDisplay();
    } 


 public void BlankDisplay() {
    nameOfPub.setText("");
    nameOfJour.setText("");
    volumeOfJour.setText("");
    locConf.setText("");
  
}
}}
```

Also, the searched data needs to be sorted according to "author", which I tried to implement but failed miserably in that too.
The only thing I have omitted from my whole code is the actionlistener of other buttons(which should not be a barrier for reproducing the problem on your system, I guess)

Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Start with the working demo from the Swing tutorial on [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting). The example works with simple filtering on one field. So modify to get it working with two fields. Then if you still have problems you have a proper [mre] to post.

Comment: @camickr I did actually dig into this document and then try to make all those textfield searches merge by myself but to no avail.

Comment: *".. try to make all those textfield searches merge by myself but to no avail."* It seems time to progress to the latter part of the suggestion by @camickr - post a [mre].

Comment: I have edited my code, providing a reprex @camickr

Comment: I have provided a reprex @AndrewThompson

Comment: I tired copy/pasting that into my IDE & got too many errors to count. Then I added imports and that was reduced to 3 compile errors. Plus it doesn't look like you spent much effort narrowing it down to just the important bits. For example: Does it really require 14 text fields to demonstrate the problem? As in, it works with 13, but on adding the 14th, 'kaboom' it breaks? I shouldn't need to point out this, but there is exactly one person who has an *interest* in solving this. You. For everyone else, it's purely academic. If you cannot prepare an MRE, or are not capable, doubt it will B solve.

Comment: I am really sorry for being sloppy sir @AndrewThompson. It's just that I am running close to deadline on this project. This time the code has been tested and compiled and truly a reprex. Now it has only 4 input fields. Please don't be mad at me, I am sorry for earlier. You guys are my only hope...

Comment: *I am running close to deadline on this project.* - well you need to work on your time management skills. We also have limited to to help people and will concentrate our time on people who make an effort to post a complete and accurate question will all the information needed to solve the problem.  *Now it has only 4 input fields.* - again why 4. You question is about multiple. So if you can do it for 2 it should work for 4. The less code posted the easier for us to see what you are doing.

Comment: Also, this code looks nothing like the code from the tutorial: 1) you are not creating the GUI on the Event Dispatch Thread (EDT). 2) There is no data "hardcoded" in the table. We are not interested you your "add" functionality, that part works. We don't have time to manually add data each time we make a change and test. Your question is about "filtering". We should only need to type into the text fields and click the button to see how the filtering works 3) method names should not start with an upper case character 4) variable names should not start with an upper case character.